# Does set follow-fork-mode child work when debugging via gdbserver ?

Tags: linux, gdbserver

I am running a program via target extended-remote host:port and connecting to a target box, since i want to debug a the child process which gets created via vfork and then execv immediately, i am putting set follow-fork-mode child in the host system. But the gdb is tracking only the parent process even after new process is created.
Note: I tried using 
set follow-fork-mode child
set detach-on-fork off
but nothing works.
Any idea how to get over this and trace my child process via gdbserver

Comment: Are you sure that the child process got forked successfully? If you set follow-fork-mode child, GDB should track the child process after a successful exec.

Comment: @Ashok - Yes child process got forked and execv successfully,i got debug prints from that process. FYI I am running on a mips target.
Also even catch vfork is not getting caught in the host gdb.

Comment: One more thing, the child process is actually a separate elf file which gets executed spawned from parent process via execv. I guess the  gdb is not able to find the symbol tables of the child process.

Comment: Even if it couldn't find symbols it should still able to track the child process. After spawning child process, can you get its process ID and attach it to GDB to see if it works?

Comment: I already tried this, after the process has been spawned put a break point in the parent parent api and then tried to attach the child process id in the gdb host but it says already a program is running do you want to terminate it. I even tried to set break point in child process api at that point but it says symbol is not present.

Comment: When the child process is spawned, instead of attaching the child to the existing GDB session, can you attach the child on to the new GDB session?

Comment: when i try to connect to the gdbserver via one more session, like
target extended-remote 10.197.20.7:2345 
connection is refused, since already it is already connection from one session.
I am not sure how to connect to gdbserver via one more gdb session.

Comment: Any idea how to connect to dbserver via one more session since already it is connected ?

Comment: Add sleep at the beginning of child process. When the child process gets spawned by parent, note the child process id and terminate existing gdbserver session. Start a new one and attach child to it.